# Possible to highlight a textbox in SSRS with alternating colors?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS 2012 and it has alternating colors using an Expression for the Fill like so:

`= IIf (RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "WhiteSmoke", "White")`

I want to highlight a field based on a value of a Field (in this case it's called R). I tried this:

`= IIf (Fields!R.Value > 5, "Yellow" ,(IIf RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "WhiteSmoke", "White"))`

But I got an error when I preview the report.

`The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'R' contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolutoin failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.`

How can I implement what I want?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a syntax error with the IIf / parenthesis?

Comment: No I'm not sure! The first expression works fine, second one doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIf(Fields!R.Value > 5
  , "Yellow"
  , IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "WhiteSmoke", "White"))
```